# Почему код не выполняется и возникает ошибка?

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка

Код вписывался в Jupyternotebook.

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
print (x*60 + y)
6
60
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-486d7a7a7fc4> in <module>
      1 x = int(input())
      2 y = int(input())
----> 3 print (x*60 + y)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо где-то ранее вы присвоили переменной `print` какое-то целое значение. Не делайте так, не называйте свои переменные так же, как называются встроенные функции питона.